# CRM 2011 Plugin - Check if OptionSet is not empty

Tags: plugins, null, dynamics-crm-2011

I am writing a plugin where I check if a particular value of a field, an Option Set is equal to a specific value and if so, then I do certain actions.

Now, within the plugin C# code, how can I check that the Option Set field is not null - i.e., is set to the Default Value?

What I did (clearly, that is wrong) because, it never went past the Null check statement. And, if I did not have the check, then I get this error message

**Error**:

```
Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): CRM.AppStateHandler.Plugins.PostApplicationCreate: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**Code**:

```js
application applicationEntity = entity.ToEntity<new_application>();
if (new_applicationEntity.new_Applicationstatus != null)
{
    var applicationStatus = applicationEntity.new_Applicationstatus.Value;
    if (applicationStatus == CRMConstants.EntityApplication.Attributes.ApplicationStatusOptions.Applying)
    {
        //my logic
    }
}
```

File constants.cs has the following

```cs
class CRMConstants
{
    public struct EntityApplication
    {
        public struct Attributes
        {
            public struct ApplicationStatusOptions
            {
                // More before this
                public const int Applying = 100000006;
                // More to come
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking:

```
if (new_applicationEntity.new_Applicationstatus != null)
```

but you need to check:

```
if (applicationEntity.new_Applicationstatus != null)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think SergeyS has your fix, but I'll add some other (hopefully) helpful comments.

Don't custom create structs for your Option Set Values.  Use the [CrmSrvcUtil](http://www.develop1.net/public/post/Generate-Early-Bound-OptionSet-enums.aspx) to create enums for you automatically.

I get annoyed with having to check for OptionSetValues being null or not, so I use these extension methods to make my life easier:

```c#
/// <summary>
/// Returns the value of the OptionSetValue, or int.MinValue if it is null
/// </summary>
/// <param name="osv"></param>
/// <param name="value"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static int GetValueOrDefault(this OptionSetValue osv)
{
    return GetValueOrDefault(osv, int.MinValue);
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns the value of the OptionSetValue, or int.MinValue if it is null
/// </summary>
/// <param name="osv"></param>
/// <param name="value"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static int GetValueOrDefault(this OptionSetValue osv, int defaultValue)
{
    if (osv == null)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    else
    {
        return osv.Value;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Allows for Null safe Equals Comparison for more concise code.  ie.
/// if(contact.GenderCode.NullSafeEquals(1))
/// vs.
/// if(contact.GenderCode != null && contact.gendercode.Value == 1)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="osv"></param>
/// <param name="value"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool NullSafeEquals(this OptionSetValue osv, int value)
{
    if (osv == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return osv.Value == value;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Allows for Null safe Equals Comparison for more concise code.  ie.
/// if(contact.GenderCode.NullSafeEquals(new OptionSet(1)))
/// vs.
/// if(contact.GenderCode != null && contact.gendercode.Value == new OptionSet(1))
/// </summary>
/// <param name="osv"></param>
/// <param name="value"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool NullSafeEquals(this OptionSetValue osv, OptionSetValue value)
{
    if (osv == null)
    {
        return osv == value;
    }
    else
    {
        return osv.Equals(value);
    }
}
```

There are two methods each with an overload:

- GetValueOrDefault - This is equivalent to the Nullable.GetValueOrDefault().  The one difference is rather than defaulting to 0, I default to `int.MinValue` to make sure I don't accidentally match on a 0 optionset value.  The Overload allows you to specify the default value if you'd like.
- NullSafeEquals - This is the one you'd be using in your code to not have to check for null

```c#
application applicationEntity = entity.ToEntity<new_application>();
if (applicationEntity.new_Applicationstatus.NullSafeEquals(CRMConstants.EntityApplication.Attributes.ApplicationStatusOptions.Applying))
{
    //my logic
}
```

Comment: could you outline the procedure for using CRMCrvcUtil to generate enums?  Does this include option set values for custom fields?

Comment: @DeveloperM Check this out:  http://www.develop1.net/public/post/Generate-Early-Bound-OptionSet-enums.aspx  Conversly, I'm also creating a plugin for the XrmToolBox to this plus more...  Hopefully I'll get it out in a week or two.

Comment: thanks for the link. I saw that some months ago and followed the directions but the file generated did not contain the enums, as expected.  I will try again, perhaps I had a typo or the wrong rollup....

Comment: @DeveloperM, don't know if you're still working on this, but I did manage to publish my Early Bound Entity Generator: https://xrmearlyboundgenerator.codeplex.com/